# Calling a specific function only when a certain condition is true

Tags: javascript, function

what would be the ideal way of calling a function only when a certain condition is true?

```js
var myVar = setInterval(function() {
                       updateData();
                     }, 2000);
```

calls `updateData()` every 2s, and I could have that condition inside `updateData()` that only executes the main action if the condition is true... so something like:

```
function updateData() {

  if (certainCondition) { 
      // do stuff 
  }
}
```

but we're still calling the function every 2s regardless of whether the condition is true or not

Comment: Use clearInterval to disable the loop until you need it.

Comment: wrapping what? @NathanBarel

Comment: well but how am I signalling to enable/disable the loop without having to continuously call this function @John

Comment: what is your condition?

Comment: so in my main code, i'm reading the data off CSV file, but I only want to do so when there's new data in the file i.e when the current file size != previous file size

Comment: why is it important not to call `updateData` every two seconds? if the condition is false nothing will execute

Comment: I don't want to hardcode the time here. The CSV file is appended by a different program and it could update in less than 2s or whatever time I specify or whatever...

Comment: you can either poll for changes (using file size or any other mechanism) or you can be reactive by making the program that changes the CSV file also trigger your logic

Comment: your second point seems to be an ideal case, but how do I call a JS function within a C++ app?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to call the function as long your condition is true? if so, let say you have a flag initialized with true, and if your condition will turn into false so you will change this flag to false and exit your loop.

```
var flag = true;
while(flag) {
  function updateData() {
// checking here your condition- if it false so: flag=false
    if (flag) { 
      // do stuff 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to exit the loop. It's just I want to contiually call `updateData()` when a certain condition is true only. and your logic seems pretty similar to what I have in the description except I'm calling every 2s

Comment: so  you want to call this function only when  there's new data in the file, and you want to activate it in a fixed time difference (scaning your file). am I right?

Comment: I only want to call `updateData()` function where's there's a new data in the file... so I guess the only way is to constantly check for the file size and if it's different, call `updateData()`?

Comment: Ok the changing in your file should somehow call the function (there is no point to call the function constantly although it could work but it doesn't efficient) , how and when the reading of the csv file is done?

Answer (score 0):

maybe try something like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
  updateData(condition);
}, 2000);

updateData = (condition) => {
  if (condition) {
    ....<run coode>....
  }
}
```